# Javascript cannot call cross-method from the same class

Tags: javascript, oop, object

I'm trying to access to the method 'render' of my class, in another method of this same class. 
But got the error

> "Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Window] has no method 'render' "

Here is my code :

```
 function myObject(options) {
    this.top_offset = 100;
    this.right_offset = 50;
};

myObject.prototype.render = function() {
    alert ("render");
};

myObject.prototype.getContent = function(data, params) {
    // do something with the data
    alert('done');
    // !not working here!
    this.render();
}
```

Any idea what I'm doing wrong ?
Thanks !

**EDIT**

The example below is working, the difference with my real code is that I'm instanciating the object before an asynchronous call (get), and that the method of my object is used as a call back function.

```
// using the object
var o = new myObject('plop');

$.getJSON(url, toSend, function(data) {
    }).success(function(e) {
    myObject.getContent(e)
    };
```

Comment: you're not using the `new` operator when instantiating your `myObject`, and `this` is pointing to the window object instead of the `myObject` object. http://jsfiddle.net/vkKJg/

Comment: @jbabey: If that's the problem, then how is `getContent` even being run?

Comment: You need to show us the complete code, including how you instantiate the object and how you make the call to `getContent()`

Comment: @Zecc I'm instanciating the object before an asynchrous call (get), and the function getContent is used as the call back of my get

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update:**
Meanwhile I'm seeing the code you've posted and I see you are already calling your callback on an anonymous function. I guess I have to do some more thinking, then.
As of now, I'm stumped.

---

Okay, so you've commented below the question that you are calling `getContent()` through a callback.
So you code looks somewhat like this, I assume:

```
$.post(url, data, myObj.getContent);
```

It's important to understand that JavaScript doesn't really have methods. It has functions, and functions can be assigned as properties of objects, but that won't mean these functions will in any way "belong" to these objects.

The `this` inside of a function, to put it simply, can either point to the object to the left of the dot when *calling* (not declaring) the function "as a method"; or the global object (window) if you call the function "not as a method"; or it can even point to some other object arbitrary object if you use tell the function to be bound or run to it -- this can be done by using a few "methods" from `Function.prototype`: `call`, `apply`, `bind`.

You can solve your problem by either creating an anonymous function which will call  `getContent()` with you object as it's activation object, like this:

```
var cb = function(){ myObj.getContent(); }
$.post(url, data, cb);
```

or by explicitly binding your function to be run with your object as its `this`:

```
$.post(url, data, myObj.getContent.bind(myObj); )
```

The second alternative is safer, because if the value of the `myObj` variable changes between the time this code runs and the time the callback is called, you may end up calling `getContent()` on the wrong object.

Comment: I'm glad your code is working, but I'm still not sure why the code you posted doesn't work. Oh well, I've got better things to think about :) Glad I could help somehow.

Answer (score 0):

Works here:

http://jsfiddle.net/NKkzb/

```
function myObject(options) {
    this.top_offset = 100;
    this.right_offset = 50;
};

myObject.prototype.render = function() {
    alert ("render");
};

myObject.prototype.getContent = function(data, params) {
    // do something with the data
    alert('done');
    // !not working here!
    this.render();
}


var a = new myObject();
a.getContent();​
```

Guessing you're not calling your object correctly